# Count non-numeric cells using date in where clause [Google Spreadsheets]

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I need to get total of rows when the value column date is in a pre-defined range.

I want to get total of rows when column date is greater or equal than '01/03/2017' and less or equal than '03/03/2017'. (Date is in 'dd/MM/yyyy')

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) is very helpful.
QUERY has a date parser, although for this type of purpose I would always recomend using ISO6801 format to avoid day/month ambiguity.

```
"SELECT COUNT(A) 
 WHERE 
   toDate(A) >= date '2017-03-01' AND
   toDate(A) <= date '2017-03-03'"
```

Comment: You can just change the SELECT statement to COUNT(A) then.